# Spreadsheet: View the entire (long) text of selected cell

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I am not using spreadsheets very often and I am not sure whether this is a feature of common software (I'm using libreoffice calc).

I have a spreadsheet in which 50 to 200 word texts are entered in some cells. Other cells contain more appropriate data for a spreadsheet, such as numbers or single words. It is important when working with the spreadsheet to keep the cells small enough so that I can view the entire table (20 rows by 10 cols), but I would like to be able to conveniently read the entire text of one cell when this cell is focused/hovered.

Are there view modes that allow to do that in common spreadsheet tools? (Something like the comments view of powerpoint/impress, with a separate bar beside/below the normal view that would have the entire text there, or else, a possibility to have a popup note).

Else, is there a convenient way to view this table (either in its native ODS/XLSX format or after conversion) with a tool that would allow to do this conveniently? (It is not too much of an issue if it is a read-only mode).

Comment: [How to display all contents of a cell in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5892-excel-show-all-contents-in-cell.html#kutools)

Comment: [Very long text in one Libre Calc cell. Hide/unhide tool? - English - Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/very-long-text-in-one-libre-calc-cell-hide-unhide-tool/17774/2)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, the LibreOffice link is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I read the contents of a truncated cell

In LibreOffice Calc do the following:

> - check Format▸Cell▸Alignment tab▸Properties: Wrap text automatically
> - use Expand / Collapse Formula Bar to read & scroll the text.
>
> [image]

Source: [Very long text in one Libre Calc cell. Hide/unhide tool? - English - Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/very-long-text-in-one-libre-calc-cell-hide-unhide-tool/17774/2)